# return error coming back as undefined

Tags: jquery

i am calling the **google distancematrix api** and testing the values i am passing to the function as proper lat lon values.

i am getting a `results[j].distance` is `undefined` when calling the script
when it gets to the

base script that call the distance calc

```
  //get estimated distance from coords
  var site1= $('#s1id').val(), site2=$('#s2id').val();
  if(site1 != ' ' && site2 != ' '){
    initialise_geocode();
    set_origin(site1_geo)
    set_destination(site2_geo);
    distance = calcDistance();
    alert(distance);
  }
```

this is my script that i am calling

```
// add to top of page for distance matrix calculations
//<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

//setup usage variables
var geocoder= '';
var origin= '';
var destination ='';
var distance = '';

function initialise_geocode(){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function set_origin(location = null){
    origin = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
}

function set_destination(location = null){
    destination = new google.maps.LatLng(location);

}

function calcDistance() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}


function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;


    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      //addMarker(origins[i], false);
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        //addMarker(destinations[j], true);
       // outputDiv.innerHTML 
        alert('  '+ origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
            + results[j].duration.text + '<br>');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your response structure `json`. BTW why have you tagged it as a jQuery question.

Comment: hi jai, at this point i am only looking to test if i can get a valid distance returned, the longitude and latitude is pulled from an existing database and computed using google api so I know those are right, i placed an alert within the loop to check and that is where i am getting my error